# Error in Data File Handling when checking if file can be opened - Why does it occur?

Tags: c++, file-handling

While trying to use data file handling to read and write class type objects from and into a file respectively, my book shows the following code:?

```
  fstream filin;
    filin.open("Stu.dat", ios::in | ios::out);  
    if(!filin)
         {cout<< "Cannot open file!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
          getch(); return 0;
         }
     else { //DO SOMETHING}
```

However this always shows an error and displays "Cannot open file"

```
fstream filin;
if(!filin)
     {cout<< "Cannot open file!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
      getch(); return 0;
     }
 filin.open("Stu.dat", ios::in | ios::out); //Written After the if clause
```

Any idea why this happens? And also, is my book wrong or does this vary from compiler to compiler?

Comment: Why are you opening file after checking `filin` state ?

Comment: Is that your real code? The second example shouldn't print anything.

Comment: It's part of the code.

The first code sample is the one that doesn't work. Second one works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What does the second one do that the first one doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

The operator `!` is overloaded to say whether or not the stream is associated with a file.  If you check if it's associated with a file before attempting to open a file, it will always say it isn't - which is exactly right.

Call `open` (or use the overloaded constructor) before checking the stream's validity.  Your book's code order is absolutely correct, and this does not vary from compiler to compiler.

Comment: You've confused `operator!()` with `is_open()`.

Comment: But the book's code is the one giving an error. The first code sample is the one that doesn't work. Second one works fine.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Not necessarily confused.  A cast from `fstream` to `bool` results in an evaluation of a nonexistent stream.

Comment: @user3258601 Compile error or doesn't run as intended?  In the first one, the "}" at the end of the comment should not be in a comment.  And in both code snippets, `return 0;` should be on a different line than `getch();`.

Comment: @Proxy `std::fstream` is not being cast to bool, and even if it was it wouldn't return the value returned from `is_open()`, it would check the underlying stream state for certain bits that are turned on. The job of `operator!` is to return `fail()`. It is an inherited member function of `std::fstream`.

Comment: `return 0;` and `getch();` can too be on the same line. That will compile just fine.